# Increment numbers when value changes in another column in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

In Excel I need to create a **calculator** for the **timekeeping system** in my book.

I thought of a **date with an alphanumeric code** (Reading from right to left)

- **A** = **day** (1 Banks Orbital rotation) (24 Earth hours)
- **S** = **year** (6.54167 rotations, 1 orbital period)
- **D** = **groups of 55.79614991 years** (365 rotations, 56 orbital periods)

So starting from D0S0A0:

- Every time the Banks Orbital rotates on itself it adds +1 to the value of A.
- Every time this value of A reaches “6.54167” +1 is added to the value of S, because after that amount of rotations the Banks Orbital has also completed an orbital period (“Year”).
- Finally, whenever S reaches “55.79614991”, I reset its value to zero and add +1 to the value of D (This last time signature is systematic, used to group the value of S, which would otherwise be too long).

How can I ***create a calculator of my date in Excel***?
(It should allow me to write any alphanumeric date (E.g. D34S04A04) and give me the days and/or years (E.g. 04th day of Banks Orbital's year 1908, or 12 406 Banks Orbital's days/rotation) 
and vice versa :D)

The **input** would be the number of rotation of the orbital structure (1 rotation = 1 Orbital’s day = D0S0A1), and the output should be this number of rotation converted in my date system (Through the values I listed above). And vice versa (Input D0S0A1 —> Output number of rotation) :D Let me know if it’s not clear.

**[Markdown table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIxqB.png)**

| Banks Orbital's Day (1 rotation, 24 Earth hours) |  | INSERT NUMBER | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Banks Orbital's Year (1 orbital periods or 6,5 Rotation) |  | THE NUMBER WILL BE CALCULATED, based on day NUMBER | years |
| Banks Orbital's Group of Years (1 orbital periods or 6,5 Rotation) |  | THE NUMBER WILL BE CALCULATED, based on day or year (?) NUMBER | group of 56 years |
| Result in | A | 0 (up to 6.5, then back to 0) | Day |
|  | S | 0 (+1 when A reaches 6.5. Once it reach 56, it return to 0) | Year |
|  | D | 0 (+1 when S reaches 56) | Group of 56 years |
| So, D0S0A0 is the initial condition (the orbital structure is created). D0S0A1 is its first rotation, which corresponds to Day 1. D0S55A1 = Year55Day1 D1S0A1 = Year56Day1 D2S50A1 = Year167(56x2+55)Day1 |  |  |  |

Please be exhaustive, I'm not familiar with excel.
Thanks!
(It lets me copy and view the table as text, if that's a problem let me know!
Thanks! :D)

Comment: Could you show a table of samples of what you mean and how you expect it to look/behave using markdown table? https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: Thanks, where can i show you the table?

Comment: In the post (by editing the post)

Comment: I did it. If the table doesn't render correctly, you can go to the imgur link created by stack overflow :D

Comment: @JiunoD the whole point of using Table Markdown is to put the Markdown output in the question as text, SO renders it, so we can copy it for working on your sample, not putting the image, this doesn't help to copy the information into excel.

Comment: So you want a cell input in days/years / date value as a starting point? Your table is not showing how you would expect it to look like

Comment: Yeah. I would like a calculator that: knowing the total rotations/days of the Banks Orbital calculates the date with the DxSxAx format, and vice versa by writing a DxSxAx date in the calculator, the total days are given.

Comment: Then an essential thing is missing: what earth date/time represents the start?

Comment: @P.b Hi, I actually don't want to convert my date (DxSxAx) to a Human date (E.g. JAN 23 2023). The start date is D0S0A0, which corresponds to 0 rotations/days of the Banks Orbital. I would like entering DxSxAx (x is a value, independent for D/S/A) to calculate the amount of rotations the ring has done since the conclusion of its construction (and vice versa)

Comment: x of A = 1 rotation (Rotation Period) = 1 "Banks Orbital Day" (How long it takes for the light of the Star to illuminate a certain point twice in a row) = approximately 24 Earth hours. x of S = 6.5 rotations = 6.5 Banks Orbital Days = 6.5 Earth days (6 days and 13 hours to be precise). x of D = 56 S or 365 A (rotation/Banks Orbital days) = 365 Earth days. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: If you need to explain your question in the comments it usually means you can better edit your question to better explain. See my answer, where I used different values and their results. Sharing a markdown table with values shown like that would have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the number of rotations based on your date system input in - for instance - `A1` you could use:

```
=SUM(TEXTSPLIT(A1,CHAR({65,68,83}),,1)*{365, 6.54167, 1})
```

Where the text in `A1` is split by character 65 (`A`), 68 (`D`) and 83 (`S`) and the resulting array is calculated by the array `{365, 6.54167, 1}`

To calculate the other way around from - for instance - `B1` you could use:

```
=LET(D, INT(B1/365),
     S, INT(MOD(B1,365)/6.54167),
     A, B1-(S*6.54167)-(D*365),
"D"&D & "S"&S & "A"&A)
```

[image]

These would actually be two separate questions, since the logic of the two formulas are very different.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the cells to create in excel. When you type in a value for A in the cell A2, B2 will populate the calculated result and display it.

Enter the below text into the B2 cell in the excel chart:
="D"&TEXT(D2,"0")&"S"&TEXT(F2,"0")&"A"&TEXT(E2,"0")

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | InputA | Solution | S_Float | D | A_Now | S_Now | A_Factor | S_Factor |
| 2 |  | Populate with B2 code from above | =A2/E2 | =INT(C2/F2) | =INT(A2-INT(C2)*G2) | =INT(C2-D2*H2) | 6.54167 | 55.79614991 |

The INT() function does not round. It simply removes the decimal. This means you will get the count as expected in the way you described the problem.

I hope that helps. Please come back if you have any issues, or to mark your question as resolved/answered.

Comment: Maybe I did not say it clear enough.
The date does not include hours or days, and is in no way tied to a Human system of measuring time.
In addition, the date is read from right to left, where
A = day (1 rotation)
S = year (6.5 rotations, 1 orbital period)
D = groups of 56 years (365 rotations, 56 orbital periods)

Comment: What is your input? What data will you enter into your calculator to get a result?

Comment: My input would be the number of rotation of the orbital structure (1 rotation = 1 Orbital’s day = D0S0A1). And vice versa (Input D0S0A1 —> Output number of rotation) :D Let me know if it’s not clear.

Comment: I believe I have what you need now. I have updated the sheet above to reflect the code you need in each cell of your sheet. This gives you the requested feedback with some tools for observing the results in more depth.